# Vb.net NO value given for one or more given parameters

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
Dim strSql As String = "Select EmpName,Count(EmpName) from tblPO where OrderType='" &
                           "B2B" & "' and POExpireDate < @LogDate Group By EmpName"
Dim tstDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim dateAsString As String = tstDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDate", CType(dateAsString, String))
Dim dtb As New DataTable

Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, con)
    dad.Fill(dtb)
End Using
con.Close()
```

I'm working in VB.NET

> NO value given for one or more given parameters

error coming while filling datatable..why...how could I fix this.
pls help

Comment: Check if you have mispelled some column names or even the table name. This error often is caused by this mispelling

Comment: NO everything is currect,,,,after giving POExpireDate pblm Coming

Comment: If the column `POExpireDate` has a date or datetime type, pass the date as `DateTime` (VB alias `Date`), not as `String`: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDate", DateTime.Now)`. The command parameters do not cause a string concatenation of the SQL, but are passed to the database "as is" together with the unchanged SQL.

Comment: Dim strSql As String = "Select EmpName,Count(EmpName) from tblPO where OrderType='" & "B2B" & "' and POExpireDate < @LogDate Group By EmpName"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDate",CType(Date.Today, DateTime))

Comment: given like that....still Same pblm

Comment: Dim strSql As String = "Select EmpName,Count(EmpName) from tblPO where OrderType='" & "B2B" & "' and POExpireDate < @LogDate Group By EmpName"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogDate",CType(Date.Today, DateTime)) Given like this still Same pblm

Comment: So if you remove the _and POExpireDate < @LogData_ (and of course the parameter) your code works?

Comment: OLEDB uses positional parameters. Try to replace `@LogDate` with `?` in the SQL command. See "Remarks" in [OleDbParameter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2). Note: in `CType(Date.Today, DateTime)` the `CType` is useless, since `Date.Today` is a `DateTime` already.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing your strSql and the connection to the data adapter but not the command which is what contains the parameter. Pass the command instead

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Using blocks ensure that your database objects are 
    'Closed And Disposed even if there Is an error.
    Dim dtb As New DataTable
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
        Dim strSql As String = "Select EmpName,Count(EmpName) from tblPO where OrderType = 'B2B' and POExpireDate < @LogDate Group By EmpName;"
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strSql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LogDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now
            'On the next line pass the command, no need to pass connection
            'because it has already been passed to the constructor of the command
            Using dad As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                dad.Fill(dtb)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept it as answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.